# I want to automate my choice when I use Garch.fit in R studio

Tags: r

```
library(olsrr)
library(rugarch)
library(dynlm)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(fGarch)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(FinTS)
library(tseries)
library(timetk)
library(tidyquant)
library(quantmod)
library(stats)
library(car)
library(ggplot2)
library(qqplotr)
library(xts)

SP500dailydat<-tq_get("^GSPC", from = '2000-02-01', to = "2020-02-01",get = "stock.prices")

getSymbols("^GSPC", from='2000-02-01',to='2020-02-01')

GSPC_Daily_Returns=(diff(GSPC$GSPC.Adjusted, lag=1))

GSPC_Daily_Returns_ACF<-GSPC_Daily_Returns[complete.cases(GSPC_Daily_Returns),]

Garch.fit <- garchFit(~garch(1,1), data = GSPC_Daily_Returns_ACF$GSPC.Adjusted, trace =T)
plot(Garch.fit)
2
plot(Garch.fit)
3
```

when I knit to pdf it says:

> Error in menus(choices = paste(" ", choices), title = " Make a plot selection(or 0 to exit):" menue cannot be used non-interactively

Is there a way to automate my choice of 2 and 3 without me having to input them into the console because that's the problem when I Knit to pdf?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we provide data to the code. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: okay i updated it, thats how i got the data to the code.

Comment: Much better, we still have to guess your libraries though. Imagine, one just starts R, provide them _everything_ they need to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Try parameter `which` inside the `plot` function.

```
plot(Garch.fit, which = 2)
plot(Garch.fit, which = 2:3)
```